# How to convert SceneKit Coordinates to SpriteKit coordinates through an "SK3DNode"?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, scenekit

In a SpriteKit project, I've begun to use some 3D objects for visual effects. Getting a scene file onto the screen with an .scn file was pretty easy using the `SK3DNode`, but I've been having trouble getting touches to work on the 3D objects inside the scene so that I can handle them accordingly.

I have an SK3DNode subclass that is instantiated through a static method. The initialize method doesn't do anything related to the SK3DNode's properties:

```
SceneKitManager *sceneKitManager = [SceneKitManager nodeWithViewportSize:sprite.size];
[sceneKitManager setPosition: sprite.position];
[sceneKitManager setPlaying:YES];
[sceneKitManager setScnScene:[SCNScene sceneNamed:@"file.scn"]];
[sceneKitManager setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
SCNNode *pov = [sceneKitManager.scnScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"camera" recursively:NO];
[sceneKitManager setPointOfView:pov];
[sceneKitManager initialize];

return sceneKitManager;
```

and then, in the same subclass, I have the touchesBegan method, which attempts to unproject the point from the 3D scene and make it usable in SpriteKit's 2D coordinate system. However, my screenCoordinates variable is always zero:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"TOUCHED");

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    vector_float3 touchVector = {touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y, 0.5};
    SCNVector3 unprojectedVector = SCNVector3FromFloat3([self unprojectPoint:touchVector]);

    NSArray *result = [self hitTest:CGPointMake(unprojectedVector.x, unprojectedVector.y) options:NULL];

    if([result count] > 0) {
        SCNHitTestResult *hitResult = [result firstObject];
        [hitResult.node removeFromParentNode];
    }
}
```

Any help is certainly appreciated, and I can provide more detail or background if I've left anything out.